# How to select music from local and sd in react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to get musics from lacal and sd on device that after select from them in some work
But i can not find soltion for this on expo any body can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only want to pick a audio, then this option you can see.

```
import React from 'react';
import { DocumentPicker } from 'expo';
```

call this pickDocument method from UI

```
pickDocument = async () => {
 let options = {
  type:"/mp3"
 }
 let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync(options);
 alert(result.uri);
 console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for anwering but some change has aoccured in syntax

Comment: And i have new one question whrer going selected file?

Comment: In the result variable, you can get all file-related info's link URI, file size, etc.  once you pick.